# Interpreting interaction between a within-subject factor and a between-subject-factor

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, interaction, interpretation

I am not sure how to interpret the following interaction between the within-subject factor "prime" and the between-subject-factor "group" (DV are response times). The outcome is slightly not significant (F (3, 38) = 2,797, p = 0.053, Its a mixed ANOVA with group as between-subject variable and prime, consistency, perspective as repeated measures with 2 levels each. prime, consistency and consistency*perspective are significant p<0.001), but I am nevertheless interested on how I could interpret it if it were significant (if that makes sense).
Am I even allowed to interpret it because the interaction between the "high_anx" and "high_avoid" groups are disordinal and also between "high_avoid" and "high_both". 
Or could I say for instance that participants in the high_avoid, high_both and low both groups reacted faster for prime 1 and slower for prime 2?
[image]

For group in separate lines:

[image]

Comment: what is  .053 ?  is ir alpha or F-statistics ? What is  your anova  model ?

Comment: F (3, 38) = 2,797, p = 0.053, Its a mixed ANOVA with group as between-subject variable and prime, consistency, perspective as repeated measures with 2 levels each. prime, consistency and consistency*perspective are significant p<0.001

Comment: For me the question would be "how do the primes work in the different groups".
So i would switch group and prime in the plot (prime on the x-axis and groups as different lines). 

I would also first try to consider the effect size. Your plot might look like a hughe effect, but the differences in reaction-time might still be quite small (if the y-axis is reaction time in seconds, than alle the group means would be somewhere between 2,90 and 2,96). You could compare this values with range or SD of your sample to figure something out

Comment: Yeah exactly, so is it legit to say then, that for the last 3 groups they reacted faster with prime 1 than with prime 2? With the first group it would be reverse then.

Comment: I logarithmized the response times because they were not all normally distributed. I re-ran the anova and estimated the effect size for it (partial eta² = 0.181) so actually a big effect size.

Comment: For me this would mean, that there is no difference between the primes in the high anxiety group. 
In the other groups it looks like prime1 leads to faster responses than prime2. To further explore this you could use some post-hog tests and check the differences between the various prime X Group combinations (assuming that the interaction effect was significant) - i think in spss it needs a bit of coding to get the significance tests for the group-comparision.

Comment: I think you are referring to simple effects analysis? Anyway I did simple effects and the outcome is a bit confusing. The prime*group interaction was not significant in the first place (p = 0.053), but in simple effects (tested the effects of prime within the groups) I now have a significant difference between prime1 and consistency and perspective. For consistency the levels were  (consistent, inconsistent) and for perspective (self, other). So in "consistent",  "self" trials with prime1 there is a significant difference for simple effects...

Comment: But I think as the interaction was not significant in the first place, the simple effects are not allowed to do right? So the only thing one could say is that although the interaction was not significant the 3 last groups reacted faster to prime1 than prime2?

Comment: Yes, since the interaction is not significant there is no reason to belief, that the effect is different between groups, so there is no reason to look for further effect-differences between the groups. 
But alpha .05 is just a man made point. Maybe if you add another few participants p would drop below .05. 
So i would start thinking about an explanation for the Data. Do you have any theoretical idea/explanation why anx-only participants should be effected in such a different way then all the other groups?

Comment: Yes, actually I should have expected it. From previous studies it is known that with priming, the "attachment style" (so secure, anxious, avoidant) can be activated, but just with a prime which is attachment-related. In my case the threat prime was not, and another study actually found that with attachment-unrelated primes the effect does not work for anxious individuals. For the data I know that it is all but good, because it was collected in a very unstandardized way (a few participant in the lab and a few at home with a laptop).

Comment: But anyway I wanted to test if unrelated primes work too, and obviously they do not. Or they work and my sample was just too small (n=42) and the data were collected in a bad manner.

Comment: Ok so I looked further into my data and calculated the inverse efficiency scores, there I found 4 outlier values which I could not get rid of by transforming the data, so I just excluded the 4 outlying values and now the prime*group interaction is significant F (3, 36) = 3,37, p = 0.029, is that approach ok? I also tried to replace the outlying values with the mean + 3x the std. but they stay outliers, so I do not really know what else to do but exlude them

Comment: I also made 2 new variables for prime only (threat, neutral) and ran simple effects, and there are significant differences between the 2 primes for high_avoid and high_both but the overall interaction between prime*group is not significant.